# Tab Bar Controller embedded in Nav Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I set up the bar title for each tab, but it keeps getting stuck with the previous tab name.

I set it under `viewDididLoad()`:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setNavBar()
}
func setNavBar() {
    tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = ""
}
```

The `navigationBar`'s title should change when I select a new tab, but it remains the same.

Comment: Embed each view controller of the tabBarController in a navigationController

Comment: @RajeshKumarR i fixed it. by calling the function in a viewWillAppear() function

Comment: Embeding each view controller of the tabBarController in a navigationController will be useful for navigating to other view controllers. Any way if the problem is solved please delete the question